# Is using get_object_vars() or json_encode() very bad for encapsulation?

Tags: php, encapsulation

**Solution found in the comment**: use the JsonSerializable interface

I am looking for the most proper way to create an array from an object properties.

The object properties would would have to store the keys and values pairs I need in the array.

I do know that get_object_vars() and json_encode() will retrieve public class fields only, but that lead to some issues regarding encapsulation.

Which method below would be considered as the best practice?

**Using public fields with get_object_vars**

In that case, the fields name must match with the array keys I need.

```
class Foo{

   public string $name;

   // Method is kind of optional since the field is public
   public function setName(string $name):void{

      $this->name = $name;
   }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setName('bar');

var_dump(get_object_vars($foo));
```

- Pros: Super straightforward
- Cons: No encapsulation. Fields I need to make the array must be set to public

**Using an intermediate class to build the array**

```
class Foo{

   private string $name;

   public function setName(string $name):void{

      $this->name = $name;
   }

   public function getName():string{

       return $this->name;
   }
}

$foo = new Foo();

$foo->setName('bar');

$builder = new ArrayBuilderFromFoo($foo);

var_dump($builder->createArray());
```

- Pros: Encapsulation
- Cons: Need an intermediate object to create the array

**Storing the properties in an array field and using an extra-method to retrieve the array**

```
class Foo{

   private array $properties;

   public function setName(string $name):void{

      $this->properties['name'] = $name;
   }

   public function getProperties():array{

      return $this->properties;
   }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setName('bar');

var_dump($foo->getProperties());
```

- Pros: Encapsulation
- Cons: A little less straight forward than using get_object_vars on the object. On a side note, I also lose the possibility to call json_decode directly on the object.

I know that class fields should be made private whenever it is possible to do so. Best practice advice on this use case is welcome.

Comment: The magic methode `__serialize()` may what you looking for , doc : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.serialize

Comment: You can also implement the JsonSerializable interface, which will allow you to customize which properties are included when you json_encode the object. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: The intermediate class/object approach seems a bit redundant, unless you have a builder class that does a specific transformation to the data, that you expect to use with various classes. You could just have a getter that returns all (or selected) the properties in an array, you don't have to have all your properties inside one array property for that. If you need all or selected props as JSON, follow @Don'tPanic's lead. I'd have a getter that returns "native data" that your JSON serializer calls.

Comment: There's also the broader question here, *is ___ very bad for encapsulation*. Why do we encapsulate things? **One**, *so properties can only be directly changed from within the class*. Your getters and serializers have no bearing here. **Two**, *for consistent public access/interface*. If your getters/serializers dump out any old properties in bulk, the specifics of which other code depends on, you've broken things and compromised your freedom to change the internals. Future getters would have to map that together from _current properties after Nth refactoring_ for "public calls".

Comment: @Vincent get_object_vars allow access to your private propery if you have public getters and setters,